# Как проверять активность объекта для DetailView в Django?

Tags: python, django

У модели Product есть свойство active:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    active = models.BooleanField()
```

В зависимости от значения active я хочу либо рендерить шаблон, либо выдавать 404 ошибку. Как мне это лучше всего сделать, используя вьюху DetailView?

```
class ProductPage(DetailView):
    model = Product
    template_name = 'public/productpage.html'
```

С обычным View я это в принципе конечно могу сделать. Но ведь DetailView специально создавали для таких целей, должен быть красивый способ. В документации как-то я ничего не нашел по этому поводу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть более изящное решение со специальным методом get_object_or_404:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404  
def get_object(self, slug):
    object = get_object_or_404(Product.objects, slug=slug)
```

Comment: О, выглядит удобно, опробую, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему с помощью переопределения метода get_object для класса DetailView:

```
class ProductPage(DetailView):

    model = Product
    template_name = 'public/productpage.html'

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):

        #получаем slug из url
        slug = self.kwargs.get('slug')  

        #Получаем по слагу queryset с объектом, который будем отображать
        object = Product.objects.filter(slug=slug)

        #Если active ==True, вызываем метод get, а если нет - выдаем ошибку 404    
        if object[0].active:
            return object.get()
        else:
            raise Http404
```